# Why i cannot assign new key value in nested array object that has promise based?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, mapping

I have spent two days just to know about this case

I have an array something like this:

```js
[
  {
    "Document_Code": "DC001",
    "Data": [
      {
        "uri": "url images"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "Document_Code": "DC002",
    "Data": [
      {
        "uri": "url images"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have a function to convert url images to Base64 like this:

```js
toDataURL(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        resolve(reader.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
  })
}
```

and I want to assign new key `base64` and the Base64 value into my array, so I expected to get a new array like this:

```js
[
  {
    "Document_Code": "DC001",
    "Data": [
      {
        "uri": "url images",
        "base64": "base64 value"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "Document_Code": "DC002",
    "Data": [
      {
        "uri": "url images",
        "base64": "base64 value"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried use `map` and `nested map`, but somehow I cannot assign `base64` `key` and `value`

Here's what I have tried:

```
addBase64Function(){
  const tempPromise=[]
  this.state.valueField.Document && this.state.valueField.Document.map((el)=>{
    el.Data.map((el2)=>{
      tempPromise.push(
        this.toDataURL(el2.uri)
        .then((base64)=>{
          el2.base64 = base64.split(',')[1];
        })
      )
    })
  })
  return Promise.all(tempPromise)
}

//call base64Function and console val
this.addBase64Function().then(()=>{console.log(this.state.valueField.Document)})
```

Comment: Is `console.log()` printing anything? And if so, what?

Comment: @DacreDenny `console.log()` printing my first array not my expected array, even I have tried add `console.log(el2)` below `el2.base64 = base64.split(',')[1];` code, i only get `uri`

Comment: its returning `base64` value, if it's returning `undefined` i think i would get an error when splitting it

Comment: nope, because `base64` returning `'data:image/jpeg;base64, <!-- base64 data -->'`, and i only need `base64` data, so i'm split it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange how you mutate the state, maybe try the following:

```
addBase64Function(values = []) {
  //always return a promise, even if values is undefined
  return Promise.all(
    values.map(el =>
      Promise.all(
        //for each Data prop of el add base64
        el.Data.map(el2 =>
          this.toDataURL(el2.uri).then(base64 => ({
            ...el2,
            base64: base64.split(','),
          }))
        )
        //set the data prop of el, this data has base64
      ).then(Data => ({ ...el, Data }))
    )
  );
}

//call it like this:
this.addBase64Function(this.state.valueField.Document).then(
  result => {
    console.log('result is:', result);
  }
);
```

If you want to log what base64 returns you can do the following:

```
this.toDataURL(el2.uri).then(
  base64 =>
    console.log('got base64:', base64) || {
      ...el2,
      base64: base64.split(','),
    }
)
```

Comment: Your method as well is mutating the state.

Comment: @James Are you sure? Can you point out where it does that exactly?

Comment: your code works well, because i need to assign `base64` key before `console.log` it so i add another `then((res)=>{this.state.valueField.Document = res})` before `then(){console.log(this.state.valueField.Document)}`, thank you mate, you save my day!, actually i don't really know how immutable/mutable works :(

Comment: @HMR, basically if you pass `array` or `object` to a function and modify the value, it will update directly in the original `object`.

Comment: @flix Immutable is not that hard anymore since the spread operator: `const newValue={...oldValue,prop:'changed value'}`. In React you should try to write mostly pure functions to make your life easier. `addBase64Function` was depending on `this.state.valueField.Document` but you can just pass it in as an argument. It was then mutating that and not returning it but instead you can return a new value based on `this.state.valueField.Document`. The requests you make to get the image are technically still impure but now the function is as pure as it's going to be.

Comment: @James Besides writing pure functions (pure functions don't mutate values that are passed to them); you should never mutate state because React doesn't detect that something changed when you mutate an object. When you optimize React to use pure components then [those don't get re rendered](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutate-state-bad-t264j) when you mutate state.

Comment: @James [Here](https://medium.com/@jamesjefferyuk/javascript-what-are-pure-functions-4d4d5392d49c#:~:targetText=Another%20reason%20to%20use%20pure,and%20refactoring%20code%20much%20easier.) is a pretty basic explanation of what a pure function is and some reasons why you use them.

Comment: @HMR, it has nothing to do with pure function. I just got to know that if we assign new object inside `map`, function won't mutate the passed value. There is difference in behaviour between `function mutateArray(v=[]){ return v.map(el=>el.a = newVal); }` and `function mutateArray(v=[]){ return v.map(el=>({ ...el, a: newVal})); }` The first function will mutate the original `array`. But, not second function.

Comment: @James Yes, first example you pass an impure function to map (it mutates) and second you don't. Using pure functions is kind of a big deal in React that's why I posted the references.